# Insert into table from two listbox controls

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql, ado.net

I have a requirement to insert user_id and quiz_iz into a table column,   I have the below code which works for inserting multiple selected values from one control into a table column, but I cannot figure out how to insert in 2 fields from values listed on both controls when hitting Submit,.

I am using odbc connection to mysql, thats were the table i need to insert is located....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

     private void InsertRecords(StringCollection sc, StringCollection sc2)
    {
        string ConnectionString = @"driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};server=localhost;database=db_mydb;uid=;pwd=;";
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);

        foreach (string item in sc)
        {

          const string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO jos_jquarks_users_quizzes  (quiz_id,user_id) VALUES";

            sb.AppendFormat("{0}('{1}'); ", sqlStatement, item);
            sb2.AppendFormat("{0}('{1}'); ", sqlStatement, item);

        }

        try
        {

            conn.Open();

            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sb.ToString(), conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Script", "alert('Records Successfuly Saved!');", true);

        }

        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {

            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);

        }

        finally
        {

            conn.Close();

        }

    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
        StringCollection sc2 = new StringCollection();


        foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
        {

            if (item.Selected)
            {

                sc.Add(item.Text);

            }

        }

        foreach (ListItem item in ListBox2.Items)
        {

            if (item.Selected)
            {

                sc2.Add(item.Text);

            }

        }
                InsertRecords(sc , sc2);


    }
}
```

Comment: You should think about using paramterized sql. What you are doing now is sending a open string to the server which anyone can escape and run a sql injection. Think of using a stored proc or just a paramaterized query

Comment: Not sure if I'm clear on what you're trying to do. Are you trying to insert a record for each value in sc * sc2 (each possible combination)?

Answer (score 2):

You should use nested foreach maybe.

```
foreach (string item in sc)
{
  foreach (string item in sc2)
  {
    insert sc and sc2
  }
}
```